# Dynamically move object on canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, storyboard

Scenario as follows.

I have an canvas on which I want to move, lets say an rectangel, across the screen. The way the rectangle is supposed to move is determined by one specific path (like a railway, the rectangle is supposed to only move on the rails). The position on which the rectangle is currently located is provided by external source.

Current Location is provided every ~200-500ms.

So far I have tried the following:

- simple TranslateTransform. Does the trick, but the rectangle jumps from Point a to b. No smooth Translation.
- Storyboard with a doubleAnimation

Smoother, but the rectangle doesn´t follow the required path.

- DoubleAnimationUsingPath. Rectangle is moving on the path. But now I am not able to provide the  current position by external source.

Easiest for me would be a way to use an DoubleAnimationUsingPath and providing the X-Koordinate by external source.

But I am not sure if overall storyboards and animations are the best way to tackel that Problem.

If you know of any completely different Approach I am more than happy hear about it.

Kind regards

Comment: It's not clear how coordinate arguments can influence the translation of the object along a fixed and predefined path. Sounds like you need to coerce these arguments and find the closest coordinate that describes a point of the path.

Comment: How is the animation supposed to behave when the path goes vertically or even backwards? You may perhaps simply use a DoubleAnimation from each y value to the next. Or let the object freely move along the path by means of a MatrixAnimationUsingPath that animates the Matrix property of a MatrixTransform.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get an idea of what can be done with animations, take a look at this little demo of a object moving along a track:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="track">
            <PathFigure StartPoint="200,100" IsClosed="True">
                <LineSegment Point="300,100"/>
                <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                            Size="100,100" Point="300,300"/>
                <LineSegment Point="200,300"/>
                <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                            Size="100,100" Point="200,100"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <MatrixAnimationUsingPath
                        Storyboard.TargetName="train"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Matrix"
                        PathGeometry="{StaticResource track}"
                        DoesRotateWithTangent="True"
                        Duration="0:0:10"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>

    <Path Data="{StaticResource track}" Stroke="Black"
          StrokeThickness="6"/>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource track}" Stroke="White"
          StrokeThickness="4" StrokeDashArray="2,2"/>

    <Rectangle x:Name="train" Width="10" Height="6" Fill="Red"
               Canvas.Left="-5" Canvas.Top="-3"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```